# Error message in trying to run java

Tags: java

Am getting the following error message while trying to run java. I have typed in java -version but am getting error:

```
C:\>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jvmhook on the library path, with error: Can't find
 dependent libraries
```

Comment: Have you set your PATH environment variables?

Comment: @Tharwen - considering that `java.exe` is printing an error message, it's unclear how setting the path to find it could be the solution here.

Comment: @Ernest - Sorry. I went into 'unhelpful default error message' mode for a bit there.

Answer (score 5):

Java is being invoked in a slightly abnormal way.

I have multiple answers depending on your Java version number and whether or not you wish to perform automated testing on your computer.

HP's Quick Test Professional (QTP, an automation tool) has been installed on your computer; this is the program which creates **_JAVA_OPTIONS** (and usually also **IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS**) to be what you observed in your post:

```
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

QTP puts these in place so that it can recognize Java objects, allowing you test a Java application.

It also can create environment variable
**JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** with

```
-agentlib:jvmhook
```

which is required for working with Java 1.6

If you do not require QTP to perform tests against Java applications then you can experiment with removing these environment variables. 
Pro-tip for easy reverting, just amend the Environment Variable names (e.g. rename _JAVA_OPTIONS to IGNOREME_JAVA_OPTIONS) 
*Environment variables require local admin privileges and a system restart to take affect.

If you are using Java version 1.5 or older then you can probably get away with removing **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** only.

The jasmine.jar seems to be troublesome to a number of java applications; I have had considerable difficulty with this stopping my applications from running in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable is making some very serious modifications to your Java environment -- and obviously doing it wrong, since it's not launching. I don't know what is setting that environment variable, but if it's not something you're trying to do yourself, if I were you I'd make a note of the value just in case you need to restore it, then go to your Windows "System" Control Panel and remove `_JAVA_OPTIONS` altogether.

Comment: It could also be that the `java` that is being invoked is not the jre, but possibly some script (`java.bat` if Windows??) which may be setting the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` as part of the command, in which case you **do** want to reexamine the PATH variable after all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Intellij IDE.  Removing .idea folder from project's local directory  solved this issue.