# Java program prints out "JAVA_OPTIONS"

Tags: java

I am starting to learn Java. After I run my code, I get some additional lines along with the expected output. Can someone please tell me what they mean?

**My Code:**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Hello World!!!
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What command do you use to run it?

Comment: Did you use other external JAR files?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677346/java-system-environment-variable

Comment: I ran it in Eclipse and got the same message and then I ran javac on from command prompt

Comment: Thanks Cruncher. I just realized that one of the tools that I have installed on the machine needs to set those two environment variables.

Comment: HP QTP / HPE LeanFT does set system-global _JAVA_OPTIONS  environment. For details see another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324186/error-message-in-trying-to-run-java

Answer (score 5):

That will happen if the environment variables `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS` are set. If you don't need them I suggest not setting them. If you are running it in Eclipse then I'd look into the "Run Configuration" or Eclipse's configuration. There is, per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message), no way of suppressing these messages if these variables are set, apparently.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just realized that one of the tools that I have installed on the machine needs to set those two environment variables. I can't remove those as they are being used by that tool. Is there a way I can prevent their display in my output?